# Can some one explain what this is actually doing?

Tags: vba, excel, user32

I have been searching for a way to close windows explorer using vba, and i have found something that works. However i actually have no idea what it is actually doing, or what any of it means. Could someone please explain what is happening below?

```
Private Const CLOSE_WIN = &H10
Dim Hwnd As Long

Private Declare Function apiFindWindow _
    Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassname As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) _
    As Long

Private Declare Function apiPostMessage _
    Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" _
    (ByVal Hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    lParam As Any) _
    As Long

    Hwnd = apiFindWindow("CabinetWClass", vbNullString)

    Dim retval As Long
    If (Hwnd) Then
       retval = apiPostMessage(Hwnd, CLOSE_WIN, 0, ByVal 0&)
    End If
```

Thank You

Comment: I think the big key here is that `CabinetWClass` is the Class Name for Windows Explorer (it was original called file cabinet, not Explorer). You are interacting with Windows built in API's here. You find the window with that class name then pass that to that `apiPostMessage` and tell it to `CLOSE_WIN` (`&H10`) for that particular window that was found. Ultimately the last 5 lines are the real code here. Everything above it is just declaring functions and constants to interact with the windows API that are required here.

Comment: I assume the above code snippet is missing the enclosing function signature for everything from `Hwnd = apiFindWindow(...` to `End If`? As it stands, it won't compile.

Comment: This sort of hoodoo is exactly the reason why legacy names like `CabinetWClass` stick around -- to make sure ill-conceived code like this keeps working. [Don't take it from me, though](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150619-00/?p=45341/).

Comment: Hi Inarion, Yeah there is a lot of other code in the procedure, i have just taken out the snippet for the code that i have copied.

Comment: Thanks JNevill, that gives me a little bit more of an insight i guess, still finding it quite confusing though

Comment: Reading the documentation for [FindWindowA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) and [PostMessageA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea) might be less confusing. I'd also take a look at [Using Messages and Message Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues).

Comment: It's using Win32 API functions to find a `CabinetWClass` window, then sends a `&H10` window message to that window, to close it - if you don't understand what this means, put a comment saying `'' HERE BE DRAGONS` at the top, and move on; then come back to it after you've read about the Win32 API functions involved, and the mechanics of window messenging - a subject that's way too broad to cover in a decent answer here.

Comment: OK, Thank You. Where can i find information about the CabinetWClass from?